# Need help running a loop through an array (object)/added the HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

How do I run a simple loop through an object array that will check for similarities of a previously exctracted value from a form. I am doing a project in which I am setting up a pizzeria. The user will input desired size of pizza and toppings in a form. I will then extract the values for total.

This is the JavaScript code I used to extract the values from the form:

```
let form=document.querySelector("form");
form.addEventListener("submit",(event)=>{
event.preventDefault();
// run an array through the checkbox
let topping=[];
document.querySelectorAll('[type="checkbox"]').forEach(item=>{
if (item.checked=== true)
{
topping.push(item.value);
}})
let pizzaSze=[
{size: "8 inch",cost: 8},
{size: "10 inch", cost:10},
{size: "12 inch", cost:12},
{size:"14 inch", cost:14},
];
let top=[
{type:"sausage", cost:1},
{type:"pepperoni", cost:1},
{type:"ham", cost:1},
{type:"chicken", cost:1},
{type:"onions", cost:1},
{type:"greenpeppers", cost:1},
];



//to extract the value of the text field:
let fullname=document.querySelector("#fullname").value;
let address=document.querySelector("#address").value;
let pies=document.querySelector("#pies").value;
let
```

pizzasize=document.querySelector('input[name="size"]:checked').value;

here is the HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Pizza Assignment</title>
</head>
<body>
<h>Pizza Perfect</h>
<br/><br/>
<form>
    <label for="fullname">Please Enter Your First Name:</label>
    <input type="text" required id="fullname" size="20" 
    name="fullname">
    <br/> <br/>
   
    <label for="address">Please Enter Your Address:</label>
    <input type="text" required id="address" size="20" 
    name="address">
    <br/> <br/>
   
    <label for="pies">Please Enter Number Of Pies:</label>
    <input type="number" required id="pies" size="20" 
     name="pies">
    <br/><br/>
    
    <p>Please Enter Size:</p>
    <input type="radio" id="8 inch" name="size" value="8 inch">
    <label for="8 inch">8 inch</label>
    <br/>
    <input type="radio" id="10 inch" name="size" value="10 inch">
    <label for="10 inch">10 inch</label>
    <br/>
    <input type="radio" id="12 inch" name="size" value="12 inch">
    <label for="12 inch">12 inch</label>
    <br/>
    <input type="radio" id="14 inch" name="size" value="14 inch">
    <label for="14 inch">14 inch</label>
    <br/><br/>
    <p>Toppings:</p>
    <input type="checkbox" id="pepperoni" name="topping" 
    value="pepperoni">
    <label for="pepperoni">Pepperoni</label>
    <br/>
    <input type="checkbox" id="sausage" name="topping" 
    value="sausage">
    <label for="sausage">Sausage</label>
    <br/>
    <input type="checkbox" id="ham" name="topping" value="ham">
    <label for="ham">Ham</label>
    <br/>
    <input type="checkbox" id="chicken" name="topping" 
    value="chicken">
    <label for="chicken">Chicken</label>
    <br/>
    <input type="checkbox" id="onions" name="topping" 
    value="onions">
    <label for="onions">Onions</label>
    <br/>
    <input type="checkbox" id="greenpeppers" name="topping" 
    value="greenpeppers">
    <label for="greenpeppers">Green Peppers</label>
    
        <br/><br/>
    <button type="submit">Submit Order</button>
    <button type="reset">Reset</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: Please include your html and when/how you are calling this calling this script. What object array are you attempting to loop over?

Comment: hello, I added the HTML. Thank you for your support. I really need it.

Comment: You didn't specify what object array you are attempting to loop over. Please elaborate on where you are stuck.

Comment: I added the object array for "pizza size and cost" as well as "topping type and cost". I know how to start the for loop: for (let i = 0; i < top.length; i++) {} I just don't know the syntax to look for value selected, then to extract the cost, and finally add the totals together. It's too advanced for me, but I know it can be done. at the end, I should have the totals for the selected values.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a `for` loop?

For example:

```
for (let i = 0; i < toppings.length; i++) {
    // calculate topping price
    // get current topping "value" with
    // toppings[i]
}
```

This allows you to loop through all the items in the array, and determine your total price from the toppings.

Comment: Hello, I was planning on running the "for" loop, but the problem is that I don't know how to set the parameters up correctly. In my class, I was NOT taught how to use loops that elaborately. Someone asked for the HTML. I'm going to paste it here. The only thing missing is the prices for the pizza and topping ($1 per inch) and ($1 per topping). HTML for the project:

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `for` or `forEach` loop:

With `for`:

```
var totalCost = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < pizzas.length; i++) {
    totalCost += pizzas[i]["cost"]; // Add the cost of the pizza to the total price
}
// Do anything you want with totalCost here
```

With `forEach`:

```
var totalCost = 0;
pizzas.forEach(pizza => {
    totalCost += pizza["cost"]; // Add the cost of the pizza to the total price
});
// Do anything you want with totalCost here
```

You're using an associative array where each key corresponds to a value, so, in order to access the value you need, you just have to indicate your key in the brackets. Then you just have to do the calculations you need inside of the loop.

Comment: I first want to thank you for your help. I want to ask, how does the loop know how to match the value selected (from the form) in the object array? Should there be  some sort of indicator, like in this case, the "size of the pizza=pizzasize"?Am I just missing that part from your answer? I was expecting to do something like:

Comment: How does the loop know how to match the value selected (from the form) in the object array? Should there be  some sort of indicator, like in this case, the "size of the pizza=pizzasize"?Am I just missing that part from your answer? I was expecting to do something like:  pizzasize != pizzaSze.length, where pizzasize is the value captured from the form being compared to the sizes in  pizzaSze array, then capture the cost in associated with the index, then add the total to "totalCost". Does that make sense to you. My mind knows what to do, I just can't write it.

Comment: I'm not really sure I understand, what the loop does is, for each value of your `pizzas` array, these values being themselves associative arrays, extract the value associated with the key "cost" from that associative array (that is 8, 10, 12 or whatever). For the size, it's a bit different because you entered it as a string, so either you enter your data as numbers (for a short program like that it's fine but keep in mind that it won't always be possible with large datasets), either you use a regex to isolate the numerical part, then you parse it before manipulating it.